# Python 3x : Dictionary function that returns adjacent words

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ipython

i wrote a function `nextw(fname,enc)` that from a book in .txt format returns a dictionary with a word as a key and the adjacent word as value.
For example, if my book has three 'go', one 'go on' and two 'go out', if i search dictionary['go'] my output should be ['on','out'] without repetitions. Unfortunately it doesn't work, or rather it works but only with the last adjacent word, with my book it returns just 'on' as a string, which i've checked and is actually the adjacent word to the last 'go'. How can i make it work as intended? Here's the code:

```
def nextw(fname,enc):
    with open(fname,encoding=enc) as f:
        d = {}
        data = f.read()
        #removes non-alphabetical characters from the book#
        for char in data:
            if not char.isalpha():
                data = data.replace(char,' ')
       #converts the book into lower-case and splits it in a list of words#
       data = data.lower()
       data = data.split()
       #iterates on words#
       for index in range(len(data)-1):
           searched = data[index]
           adjacent = data[index+1]
           d[searched] =adjacent
    return d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies here `d[searched] = adjacent`. You need to have something like:

```
if not searched in d.keys():
    d[searched] = list()

d[searched].append(adjacent)
```